# Определение четности числа

Tags: html, php

Здравствуйте, помогите с определением четности числа, пожалуйста.
Есть скрипт добавления записи в файл, но нужно определить, какая запись по четности(для распределения результатов слева или справа), пытался сделать функцию деления на два, и если равно нулю, то будет слева, если нет - справа. Но ведь, при делении 2 на 2 будет ноль, а при делении 4 на два будет 2, но это тоже четное, вот что можно придумать?

Comment: >>Но ведь, при делении 2 на 2 будет ноль

Я видимо что-то пропустил за последние несколько лет :( Были изменения в арифметике ? о_О

Comment: упс, да один :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть функция modulo, возвращающая остаток при делении. Для определения четности:

```
if((256 % 2) == 0)
{
    //256 делится на 2 без остатка, четное число
}
```

Подробнее: [документация](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php), [деление с остатком](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Answer (score 5):

Нужно приравнять нулю остаток от деления на два или, что то же самое, результат побитного логического "и" с единицей.